# Problems in putting JSONArray to JSONObject in a POST request

Tags: android, http-post, json

This is a POST request to server -

```
public String callServiceTotalRecords(String userName, String password, String email, String type, String start, String end, String userTimeZone, JSONArray ContentClassArr)
    {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(WEBSERVICE + type);

    HttpResponse response = null;

    String responseBody = "";

    try {

        String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString( 
                (userName + ":" + password).getBytes(), 
                Base64.NO_WRAP);


        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);

        httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("Start", start); 
    obj.put("End", end);
    obj.put("emailId", email);
    obj.put("userTimeZone", userTimeZone);
    obj.put("ContentClassArr",ContentClassArr.toString());

         httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) 
        {
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("response ok", "ok response :/");
        } 
        else 
        {
        responseBody = "";
        Log.d("response not ok", "Something went wrong :/");
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responseBody;
    }
```

But the response is **404 not found**.

```
"response not ok: Something went wrong"
```

The doubt is on ContentClassArr which is of type JSONArray formed like-

```
JSONArray ContentClassArr= new JSONArray("[\"UserLog\",\"Sheets\"]");
```

Then I am putting it in JSONObject like -

```
obj.put("ContentClassArr",ContentClassArr.toString());
```

**Typical correct json on server should be** -

```
{"emailId":"usertest@gmail.com","Start":"2014-01-09T12:51:34.110Z","userTimeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","End":"2014-01-16T12:51:34.110Z","ContentClassArr":["UserLog","Sheets"]}
```

Is it a right way of putting `JSONArray`  to `JSONObject` OR error is somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.put("ContentClassArr",ContentClassArr.toString());`

You don't call `toString()` on the `JSONArray`, you just pass it as-is.

`obj.put("ContentClassArr", ContentClassArr);`

See: [Javadocs for JsonObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

That said, that isn't your issue. A `404` from a POST means the URL is incorrect. Once you use the right URL, however, the JSON would have become an issue.

Also, please don't use capitalized variable names. It goes against the naming conventions and makes it hard to read your code. Class names are capitalized, variables aren't.

Comment: Still the same problem. Response 404. See my update in question. Any other ideas ?

Comment: and what about Basic Authorization that I did before passing json. It may also be an issue ? (OR just url).

Comment: It's the URL. Basic auth just gets put in the headers and if it were wrong but the URL was correct, you'd get a `401 forbidden`

Comment: Thank you Sir. The information was more than enough. I got it correct now.